# Custom Post Type + Custom Taxonomy = Archive Listing Page Problems

Tags: taxonomy

I have a custom post type that uses a custom taxonomy. It's working, from what I can tell, in the sense that I can create a post, and assign the custom taxonomy terms to it. Debugging shows the terms are being saved.

I guess my confusion lies in how the template hierarchy works. I copied the archive.php file and called it "taxonomy-zouk_video_level.php" and it's being called. But that file has the usual Loop in it, and no posts are found when I navigate to the URL for the term.

Am I supposed to be using a different Loop? Or am I not to use the Loop at all?

Here's my custom post type code:

```
<?php

function zouk_custom_types() { 

    $videolabels = array(
        'name'               => 'Videos',
        'singular_name'      => 'Video',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Video',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Video',
        'new_item'           => 'New Video',
        'all_items'          => 'All Videos',
        'view_item'          => 'View Video',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Videos',
        'not_found'          => 'No Videos found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Videos found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Videos'
    );

    register_post_type( 'zouk_video',
        array( 
            'labels' => $videolabels,
            'description' => __( 'A video.', 'bonestheme' ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 1,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-video', 
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'zouk_video', 'with_front' => false ), 
            'has_archive' => 'zouk_video',
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions')
        )
    ); 

    $instructorlabels = array(
        'name'               => 'Instructors',
        'singular_name'      => 'Instructor',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Instructor',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Instructor',
        'new_item'           => 'New Instructor',
        'all_items'          => 'All Instructors',
        'view_item'          => 'View Instructor',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Instructors',
        'not_found'          => 'No Instructors found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Instructors found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Instructors'
    );

    register_post_type( 'zouk_instructor', 
        array( 
            'labels' => $instructorlabels, 
            'description' => __( 'An instructor.', 'bonestheme' ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 2,  
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups', 
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'zouk_instructor', 'with_front' => false ), 
            'has_archive' => 'zouk_instructor',
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions')
        ) 
    ); 

    /* use categories with the videos */
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'zouk_video' );

}

    // adding the above to the Wordpress init
    add_action( 'init', 'zouk_custom_types');

function zouk_video_types() {   

    // now custom term for video levels
    register_taxonomy( 'zouk_video_level', 'zouk_video',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Video Levels',
            'show_admin_column' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'video-level' ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );

}

// adding the above to the Wordpress init
    add_action( 'init', 'zouk_video_types');

?>
```

Comment: `taxonomy-my_custom_type.php` this makes no sense since there is no template in hierarchy combining _taxonomy_ with _custom post type_. Which archive you are talking about precisely? What is your archive file name literally?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, was a typo. I edited the question to include the correct template name: "taxonomy-zouk_video_level.php".

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to do this:

```
'exclude_from_search' => false
```

Now the Loop is returning posts.